# How to deal with missing values in a systematic way in R with long format data

Tags: r, na, missing-data, panel-data

I have data on income for individuals for different years, and the data frame is similar to this:

```
case.id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4)
years   <- c(1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,
1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008)
income <- c(1100,NA,NA,NA,NA,1300,1500,1900,2000,NA,2200,NA, 
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 2300,2500,2000,1800,NA, 1900)
df <- data.frame(case.id, years, income)
```

I want to run a fixed effects model on this data. I don't want to exclude every case that has a missing value in one of the years, but I only want to exclude the cases either if `income` is missing for all years, or if it is missing for 4 or more subsequent years (like in the 1st `case.id`). As a note, I am originally dealing with 15 time points. I am interested in individual income trends and I don't want to make predictions for individuals with a lot of subsequent missing values.

I would be very happy if someone could help me by showing a way to deal with missing data systematically like this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe `df[df$case.id %in% names(which(!tapply(df$income,df$case.id,function(x) all(is.na(x)) || sum(is.na(x))>=4))),]` will filter the data according to the described logic, if I got it correctly.

Comment: Whatever your rule is, define a TRUE/FALSE column to encapsulate it (probably using `ave`) and then filter on that column before doing your analysis.

Comment: The package "tidyr" has the functions expand, fill and replace_na which could help.  The "missing for 4 or more subsequent years", will be more problematic than your other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're looking for windowed filter functions from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(case.id) %>% 
  arrange(years) %>% 
  mutate(exclude = cumsum(is.na(income)),
         all_na  = all(is.na(income))) %>% 
  filter(max(exclude) < 4,
         !all_na)
```

These are awesome for problems where it's easy to do the thing you want to do on one subset of your data, but you want to do it to all subsets. Usually dplyr provides a good solution.